# Warning : Failed child context type: Invalid child context 'virtualizedCell.cellKey' of type 'number' supplied to 'CellRenderer', expected 'string'

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I updgraded from react 16.2 -> 16.3-alpha-1 and react-native 0.52->0.54 and I get the warning above in the simulator.

Comment: I wasn't even using the keyExtractor property, and I got this warning anyway. Had to add this garbage noise to my code to avoid the warning. Bad API.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

To fix the error in any list components where a keyExtractor is in use, update the Component (FlatList etc) to have a **string key** with .toString(). **All keys must now be string values**.

Like below;

```
keyExtractor={item => item.index_id}
```

to

```
keyExtractor={item => item.index_id.toString()}
```

This change is a requirement for all uses of a keyExtractor so that would include React-Native components like; FlatList and ActionSheet.

Comment: Works like charm

Comment: I kept putting KEY={item => item.id} 
instead of using *keyEXTRACTOR*. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

This will solve the warning given by `React` and `React Native`.

Comment: I'm always appreciative of answers that can silence a warning without changing behavior while also working in every case

Comment: Do note that using an array index as the key for a component is a bad practice and is discouraged by the React docs (except that there's absolutely no other choice) See more here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score -2):

You could try this solution:

```js
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index.toString()}
```

Comment: this answer is already present, by user Aun Abbas. Duplicated.

Comment: I know But some time index.toString()  did not resolve the issue, So item+index.toString() is the best solution to fix the warning,